# On-click Box shadow Shadow - Javascript (not jquery)

Tags: javascript, css

I want a drop shadow to appear upon click of a image. I don't use Jquery at the moment so if possible provide a java-script solution. Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUNhD/7/

I would also like for the box shadow to only be active on whatever item is Currently Selected. (the last item clicked should be the only one with the shadow)

```
    window.onload = function(){
var box1 = document.getElementById('thumbs');
var box1Div1 = box1.getElementsByTagName('input');
var img1 = box1Div1[0]
    console.log(img1);

    img1.onclick = function(){
    img1.setAttribute("class", "BoxShadow");
   };
   };
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zUNhD/20/ ?

Comment: @Passerby Yes Thank you very much! If you want repost this as a "answer" and i will accept. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending from comment:

You can use `:active` selector to response to "click" event, and `:focus` selector to response to, well, "focus" event:

```css
input:active, input:focus{
    box-shadow:2px 2px 2px blue;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUNhD/29/)

Answer (score 2):

The function hasn't been called in your code.

```
window.onload = function(){
var box1 = document.getElementById('thumbs');
var box1Div1 = box1.getElementsByTagName('input');
var img1 = box1Div1[0];      
img1.onclick = function(){
img1.setAttribute("class", "DropShad");
};
}();
```

Here is the working fiddle ... http://jsfiddle.net/zUNhD/18/

Answer (score 1):

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E2w5K/) for some simplifications of your code. The css class wasn't assigned right, it should be preceded by a dot. Put your script tag near the ending `</body>` tag and use:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById('thumbs');
var box1Div1 = box1.getElementsByTagName('input');
var img1 = box1Div1[0]

img1.onclick = function(){
  img1.className = "DropShad";
};
```